Automating Data entry for check status and Paygroup
I have a spreadsheet with the CLIO ID and their corresponding paygroup and check status, and I am trying to create a way for CLIO to update its custom fields with these new paygroup and check status values. I know this isn't a great explanation so if any other clarifications are needed please let me know.
I tried using Zapier, but I always got errors when it came to the editing/action function
